# Dynamic layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, scrollview

I face a problem with my layout and can't solve it, maybe you can help...
I have a Horizontal Scrollview with childs and beneath a RelativeLayout with buttons... The HorizontalScrollwith grows from time to time and the RelativeLayout is simply a line of buttons.
The Buttonline is in the middle of the screen on start. Now when the scrollview grows, it pushes the buttponbar to the bottom and if its to big **out of sight**...

I want the buttonline to move to the bottom but it shoudl not dissappear if the listview gets big... it should stay on the bottom screen the whole time.
Hope I could make the issue clear.
(Right now if the listview gets big, the relativelayout disappears..)

```
<LinearLayout>
  <HorizontalScrollView>
    <LinearLayouts/>
    <ListView/>
  </HorizontalScrollView>
  <RelativeLayout/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="250dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/test />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/id0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="200dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/id1"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/w"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/h"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/test" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/id2"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/w"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/h"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/test" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm really sorry for eyecancer but the stackoverflow formatting is killing me here -.- did my best...
can't privde screenshots sorry, but its simply a list filling with lines and pushing the relativelayout out of the screen. I just want it to stay on screen.
AlignBottom is not possible because I need the Relativelayout to start near the center of the screen and THEN moving to the bottom with a growing list..

Comment: give us a screenshot of your problem and your expectations, and provide your xml full layout not just headings

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in a different linearLayout after the Horizontal.

Easy solution will be match at the bottom of the screen and allways keep it there. So with that the ListView dont affect to the buttonline.

Something like:

```
<LinearLayout>
  <HorizontalScrollView>
    <LinearLayouts/>
    <ListView/>
  </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout>
   <RelatibeLayout/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Wraping in a linear layout didn't change anything :( does the parent linear layout need some important specification?
AlignBottom is not possible because I need the Relativelayout to start near the center of the screen and THEN moving to the bottom with a growing list..